# Design review - RGB LED color mixer using PWM

Tags: pwm, 555, potentiometer, rgb, mixer

I'm trying to make an RGB color mixer. LED strip runs on 0.5-2A. It has internal resistors. LED Strip needs 5v, has one pin for that, one for red, one for green, and one for blue. Each LED module that you can cut off was about an inch an a half, actually a little less, and there's 5.5' of the strip, I think there's around 40 LEDs in the strip. I found this video online, but this is the exact LED strip I got.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sN5_Hjq_9Jg.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faNWZ3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Original schematic.*

I will be using a total of 6 volts. i saw a video where a guy made a PWM circuit, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x4RmIzUd2lk, and it looked something like this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbT2os.png)</sup>

*555-based PWM control.*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9qWGj.png)</sup>

*Tidied-up schematic.*

I meant for the threshold to connect to the trigger, but I couldn't get it to.
I'm confused on how to pick my resistors, my pot, and my capacitor, because in a different video, it said something like 1.44/(R1+R2+R2)*C1=Frequency. I assume frequency is how fast the LED flickers? In this schematic, there's 2 capacitors, which do I use in the equation? Does higher frequency mean faster flickering? How fast would be too fast for the naked eye? How do I control which I way I turn the pot to make the lights brighter. And how do I know how much current is coming out of the the output? How can I control that so it doesn't burn out my LED?

Comment: Are you sure you are using \$3 \Omega \$ resistors?

Comment: @jsotola I never said 1V?

Comment: @copper.hat No actually. I realized my mistake (I used the max current for the strip in ohm's law, when I should've used the minimum) while making the schematic, but I was going somewhere and forgot. I actually need a 9.8 ohm resistor, as with the 500 ohm pot, it would result in max of 9.61 resistance (using a parallel resistance calculator), and I need a 9.6 ohms resistor.

Comment: Your schematic says 1 V on the power supply. What is the power rating of the pots?

Comment: We need more information, there are many, many types of LED strips. If there are no specifications, at least post a few pictures.

Comment: @Transistor I'm actually gonna use 3 3.3 ohms resistors for each pot so they add up to 9.9 ohms of resistance. And I'll check later when I have more time.

Comment: @Mattman944 What more info is there to give?

Comment: @jsotola If I use a 500kΩ potentiomer and lower it to the resistance I need, would that be bad?

Comment: @jsotola I updated the post, removing some useless things, and updating the info. I also have another question at the end.

Comment: @Mattman944 I updated the post, removing some useless things, and updating the info. I also have another question at the end.

Comment: @Transistor I updated the post, removing some useless things, and updating the info. I also have another question at the end.

Comment: @copper.hat I updated the post, removing some useless things, and updating the info. I also have another question at the end.

Comment: When you move the wiper up to the top of the pot you will short out the 12  ohm resistor and apply 6 V to the LED. It will be lovely and bright for a very short time.

Comment: @Transistor So if I make the resistance the least on the pot, the resistor would short out? How could I prevent that?

Comment: @Transistor And what about my other question?

Comment: @Transistor If I just need to lower the voltage, and change the resistor, could I swap to 3 1.5 AA batteries, and use aluminum foil to make a dummy battery?

Comment: @Transistor To prevent the short circuit, would I have to use a resistor between the pot and the parallel resistor?

Comment: Let's start again. Your question doesn't explain what you're actually trying to do. (1) It looks like you are trying to either reduce your 6 V supply to 5 V or make a three-channel dimmer using potentiometers. (2) Where did you get the 0.5 A to 2.0 A current requirements? (3) Can you post a photo of the LED strip showing any scissors cut-lines if there are any. (4) How many LEDs are there in the whole strip. (5) 5 V is unusual. Are they designed to work on a USB power supply? Please [edit] your question to clarify and try to answer each of the points 1 to 5.

Comment: @Transistor. Oh sorry, I didn't notice that. I'm trying to make an RGB color mixer by dimming each individual light with a potentiometer. 1 pot for green, another for red, and another for blue.

Comment: @Transistor I got the requirements from a piece of paper that came with the lights.

Comment: @Transistor Ok. I'll have to check how many LED's. I'm not sure. And yes, they have a usb cable.

Comment: @Transistor I edited it, and found a video of the exact strip I have. So you can use that to see what it looks like.

Comment: @Transistor Can you please look at my question now, and help me out?

Comment: Why are you not using the controller that came with the LED strip?

Comment: @Transistor I want it more specifically controlled.

Comment: I have un-deleted the original image so that existing answers make sense. Please don't delete it or you make the existing answers look non-sensical. Your 555 solution is probably the right way to go but it can't drive 700 mA on its own.

Comment: @Transistor Oh, ok, I didn't think about that. And what do you mean. Where do I get that calculation of 700?

Comment: @Transistor I've looked online, but I can't find how to know how much current is coming out of it. Where did you get 700?

Comment: Read the first line of my answer.

Comment: @Transistor Oooohhh, ok. Thanks. Where would I put the 1.4 ohm resistor? Would I put it before each 555 timer? And once again, how do I calculate the current from the 555?

Comment: @Transistor Hi. If you don't mind, could you please answer my questions? I can't find the answers online.

Comment: @Transistor. I'm just gonna power the lightstrip and use a button for now. Do I put that 1.4 ohm resistor at the positive wire, or negative.

Comment: @Transistor I mean like from the battery to the sensor circuit thing. If I just put the resistor before the circuit, does that mean that the resistor value changes?

Comment: @Transistor Help please.

Answer (score 1):

What is your LED part number? Please provide a link.
Is it REALLY 2A rated?

As shown your pots are in PARALLEL with your fixed resistors so will REDUCE the resistance to below 3 Ohms.

500 Ohm pots are too large - you will have to set the wiper very near one end and have minimal control.

Each LED colour has a different voltage drop UNLESS they already have internal resistors.   Red LEDs about 2V.
Green and blue closer to 3V.

The AA supply using Alkalines will be 4.9V when new, will rapidly fall to about 4V and then over time fall to about 3.3V.
At 9.6 ohms and even 0.5A you will drop V=IR = 0.2 x 9.6 = 1.92V.
At even 0.5A if you drop 1.9V you will have too little voltage except when the battery is very new.

Giving more detail will help us help you.
Especially LED specs.

Comment: Yea, reducing the resistance was what I was going for since I couldn't find any cheap  low resistance pots.

Comment: I saw that the strip has those chip resistors. or something.

Comment: I know. When I was making the schematic, I remembered that something that made me realize I was supposed to use the minimum current for ohm's law. I was going somewhere, so I forgot to change it.

Comment: Sorry, I bought the strips from walmart. And what exactly is voltage drop?

Answer (score 1):

If the strip draws 2 A with all colours at maximum then you need about 700 mA per colour. That means that you need about \$ \frac 1 {0.7} = 1.4\ \Omega \$ per extra volt of your supply.

Now let's look at your 500 kΩ pots. These are typically rated 1/8 W being dissipated along the whole resistance track. We can calculate the maximum current from \$ P = I^2R \$. Rearranging we get \$ I_{max} = \sqrt {\frac P R} = \sqrt {\frac 1 8 \frac 1 {500k}} = \frac 1 {4,000,000} \ \text A \$. It should be clear why this isn't going to work. (Don't think that you can run higher current if you turn the pot to a lower value.)

At 500 Ω the result is \$ I_{max} =  \sqrt {\frac 1 8 \frac 1 {500}} = \frac 1 {4,000} = 0.25 \ \text {mA} \$. That's out too then.

The right way to do it is to use PWM control as does the controller that came with the LEDs.

[image]

*Figure 1. PWM signal transitioning from high pulse width (75%) to low (25%) and back again. Note amplitude remains constant. This will result in an apparent brightness of 75% and 25% of rated current. Source: [LEDnique](http://lednique.com/power-supplies/dimmable-mains-psu-control/).*

PWM, pulse width modulation, is very efficient as the LEDs are either fully on or fully off. If the PWM frequency is high enough you won't notice the flicker.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyYjkX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. A linear dimmer for one channel. R3 is an approximate value for all the resistors on one channel of the strip.*

You could try something like Figure 2 but it has a few problems. You will lose a couple of volts across Q2 so you'll never achieve full brightness with a 6 V supply.

As explained already, the right way to do this is by PWM and there are thousands of examples on the web. Just make sure you chose a circuit for common cathode LEDs, if that's what you've really got.

Comment: wow, the confusion is real. But ok, I'll look at  PWM.

Comment: Wait, I said a parallel resistor with the potentiometer.

Comment: But I still don't really understand why a pot wouldn't work. It would change the resistance, the voltage is the same, so the current should change.

Comment: The individual LED chips on the strip have 6 pins, 3 on each side, but the strip itself has 4 pins.

Comment: I found this video online, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YmPziPfaByw

Comment: Would I need to modify anything. Does the pot value matter at all? Because he said a couple different values and said they'd work.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not going to watch videos for you. I've explained in detail why the pots won't work. You might need to read it a couple of times and look up some theory to go with it. You need to start reading books if you want to learn electronics. Start with basic circuits with resistors and LEDs and measure voltages and currents. Then move on to transistors, etc. There's a lot to learn.

Comment: I mean the pot value in the circuit in the video. I couldn't tell if he was saying any value would work, or those specific ones only.

Comment: I Updated the post