# Here is a design for a RGB color mixer. Is it fine, or did I mess up somewhere? Is there room for improvement?

Tags: led, resistors, potentiometer, rgb, mixer

LED strip has resistors built in. LED strip runs on 0.5-2A. LED Strip needs 5v, has one pin for that, one for red, one for green, and one for blue. I will be using a total of 4.8 volts. Using ohms law, with the minimum current as the current in the equation, I'll need a resistance of 9.6 ohms (let me know if I did it wrong, or if If I should do it another way). The potentiometers will be 500 ohms each, with 3 resistors of 3.3 ohms wired in series, then connected to the wiper and a terminal for a resistance of 9.71 ohms. The batteries (rechargeable), once again, are in total 4.8 volts (4 1.2v) and AA https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2FDuracell-NiMH-rechargeable-blister-2500mAh%2Fdp%2FB000UL5GFI&psig=AOvVaw1YYgysQ11CnRbC6yDumiS3&ust=1587928578552000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CA0QjhxqFwoTCJD57omlhOkCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD. The button will be an LED latching button. Let me know if I'm missing any info.
[image]

Comment: This question and diagram looks (my brain says) to a question asked by another (apparent) user some weeks back. The assumptions were wrong in a number of areas then and were addressed by people. Starting again is wasting everyone's time. What relationship has this got to the other question? | | IF you need 9.6 Ohms then this is wrong as the MOST you can get per cct is 3.3 Ohms. || Using a 500 Ohm por to get adjustments of 1 to 10 Ohms puts the wiper near one end. ...Resolution is terrible and odds are the pot will be dissipating more than its designed foR ...

Comment: ... Failing to account for LED Vf for each colour type makes the solution rubbish. || What sort of batteries make 1.2V in your opinion? (NimH, Alkaline, ...?) Please cite the other question.

Comment: In addition to the other concerns, you really need to provide a real datasheet for the LEDs, or if you can't get one, draw the circuit they implement (including all resistors) or else measure the exact voltage and current as you want to run them.

Comment: this looks like a duplicate ...  [I'd like it if my circuit was checked](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/480282/id-like-it-if-my-circuit-was-checked)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon What is cct? And I accidentally had messed up. I meant 9.9. Using a parallele resistance calculator says that the equivalent resistance is 9.71 ohms.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon The LED strips already have resistors in them.

Comment: @user1850479 A datasheet? I'll look at the back and copy what I see.

Comment: I answered this question two months ago [herte](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/480284/3288) you have ignored my answer and the comments that otjhers made. You are wasting upur time. You are wasting others people's time. You are wasting my time. Read what I said in my prior answer . If you still need help after understanding what was said, ask. But do not post essentially identical duplicate questions and refuse to listen to advice given.

Answer (score 3):

This question and diagram is identical to [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/480282/3288) asked two months ago. The assumptions were wrong in a number of areas then and were addressed by people. Starting again is wasting everyone's time. What relationship has this got to the other question?

IF you need 9.6 Ohms then this is wrong as the MOST you can get per cct is 3.3 Ohms.

Using a 500 Ohm por to get adjustments of 1 to 10 Ohms puts the wiper near one end. Resolution is terrible and odds are the pot will be dissipating more than its designed for.

Failing to account for LED Vf for each colour type makes the solution rubbish.

What sort of batteries make 1.2V in your opinion? (NimH, Alkaline, ...?)